# Can't deterministically update nested dictionaries with unique first key

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, python-2.6

I'm trying to create dictionaries to mirror Networking Hardware within a Class. I've nested a couple of object attributes for ease of managing the code going forward:

```
    self.hw_profile = defaultdict(dict)        
    self.a1k2x_dict = defaultdict(dict)
    self.a1k4_dict = defaultdict(dict)
    self.a1k6_dict = defaultdict(dict)

    self.spa_none = {}

    int_map = {'local_int':"", 'local_pc':"", 'opp_dev_desc':"", 'opp_dev_match':"", 'opp_int':""}

    self.spa_6x1g = {'spa_name':"6XGE-BUILT-IN",
                      'int_type' : 'GigabitEthernet', 
                      'int_quant' : 6,
                      'int_map' : int_map
                    }                  
    self.spa_1x10g = {'spa_name' : 'SPA-1X10GE-L-V2',
                      'int_type' : 'TenGigabitEthernet', 
                      'int_quant' : 1,
                      'int_map' : int_map
                    }
    self.spa_5x1g = {'spa_name' : "SPA-5X1GE-V2", 
                      'int_type' : 'GigabitEthernet', 
                      'int_quant' : 5,
                      'int_map' : int_map
                    }
    self.a1k6_dict = {'slot0':
                        {'spa0': self.spa_1x10g, 
                         'spa1': self.spa_none, 
                         'spa2': self.spa_none,
                         'spa3': self.spa_5x1g},
                       'slot1':
                        {'spa0': self.spa_1x10g, 
                         'spa1': self.spa_1x10g, 
                         'spa2': self.spa_none,
                         'spa3': self.spa_none},
                       'slot2':
                        {'spa0': self.spa_1x10g, 
                         'spa1': self.spa_1x10g, 
                         'spa2': self.spa_none,
                         'spa3': self.spa_none}
                    }

    self.a1k2x_dict = {'slot0':
                        {'spa0': self.spa_6x1g,
                         'spa1': self.spa_5x1g, 
                         'spa2': self.spa_none,
                         'spa3': self.spa_none},
                    }
```

Now I want to take these abstract dictionaries and populate them with specific values. I've tried setting the new values with `.get`/`.update` or using simply `self.hw_profile['slot0']['spa1'] = x`, etc.

```
    elif self.hw_name == "cisco-asr-1006":
        self.hw_profile = self.a1k6_dict

    temp_dict1 = {'local_int' : "0/0/0" , 'local_pc':"", 'opp_dev_desc' : "blah1", 'opp_dev_match' : 
                self.re_core1_match, 'opp_int':"" }

    self.hw_profile.get('slot0', {}).get('spa0', {}).get('int_map', {}).update(temp_dict1)


    temp_dict2 = {'local_int' : "1/0/0" , 'local_pc':"", 'opp_dev_desc' : "blah2", 'opp_dev_match' : 
                self.re_core2_match, 'opp_int':"" }

    self.hw_profile.get('slot1', {}).get('spa0', {}).get('int_map', {}).update(temp_dict2)


    temp_dict3 = {'local_int' : "2/0/0" , 'local_pc':"", 'opp_dev_desc' : "blah", 'opp_dev_match' : 
                 self.re_alg_match, 'opp_int':"" }
    self.hw_profile.get('slot2', {}).get('spa0', {}).get('int_map', {}).update(temp_dict3)
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that no matter what I do, the first key in the dictionary seems to be ignored and ALL of the branches down the tree get written with the LAST value, as shown in this printed output of the dictionary:

```
[slot1]
  [spa2]
  [spa3]
  [spa0]
    spa_name = SPA-1X10GE-L-V2
    [int_map]
      opp_dev_desc = opposing ALG
      local_int = 2/0/0
      local_pc =
      opp_dev_match = <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x7f647551b870>
      opp_int =
    int_quant = 1
    int_type = TenGigabitEthernet
  [spa1]
    spa_name = SPA-1X10GE-L-V2
    [int_map]
      opp_dev_desc = blah
      local_int = 2/0/0
      local_pc =
      opp_dev_match = <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x7f647551b870>
      opp_int =
    int_quant = 1
    int_type = TenGigabitEthernet
[slot0]
  [spa2]
  [spa3]
    spa_name = SPA-5X1GE-V2
    [int_map]
      opp_dev_desc = blah
      local_int = 2/0/0
      local_pc =
      opp_dev_match = <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x7f647551b870>
      opp_int =
    int_quant = 5
    int_type = GigabitEthernet
  [spa0]
    spa_name = SPA-1X10GE-L-V2
    [int_map]
      opp_dev_desc = opposing ALG
      local_int = 2/0/0
      local_pc =
      opp_dev_match = <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x7f647551b870>
      opp_int =
    int_quant = 1
    int_type = TenGigabitEthernet
  [spa1]
[slot2]
  [spa2]
  [spa3]
  [spa0]
    spa_name = SPA-1X10GE-L-V2
    [int_map]
      opp_dev_desc = blah
      local_int = 2/0/0
      local_pc =
      opp_dev_match = <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x7f647551b870>
      opp_int =
    int_quant = 1
    int_type = TenGigabitEthernet
  [spa1]
    spa_name = SPA-1X10GE-L-V2
    [int_map]
      opp_dev_desc = opposing ALG
      local_int = 2/0/0
      local_pc =
      opp_dev_match = <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x7f647551b870>
      opp_int =
    int_quant = 1
    int_type = TenGigabitEthernet
```

I've tried everything I can think of here. Am I hitting a bug or am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: Could you [create a *minimal* code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Consider what will happen if you use `int_map.copy()` instead of `int_map`, `spa_none.copy()` instead of `spa_none`, `copy.deepcopy(spa_1x10g)` instead of `spa_1x10g`, etc.

Comment: thanks so much!  this was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing the same inner dictionaries multiple times in the outer dictionaries. This is why you see the last versions of the modifications you make reflected in multiple places.

As J.F. Sebastian commented, you may be able to work around the issue by copying the "prototype" dictionaries when you're adding them to the outer dictionaries (e.g. with `int_map.copy()` or `copy.deepcopy(spa_1x10g)`). This ensures that each location that references a dictionary of the same structure gets a separate instance, so they can be modified independently.

Here's a simpler example that shows the same problem you're having:

```
inner_dict = {0: 0}
outer_dict = {1: inner_dict, 2: inner_dict}

outer_dict[1][0] = 1
outer_dict[2][0] = 2

print(outer_dict)  # prints {1: {0: 2}, 2: {0: 2}}
print(outer_dict[1] is outer_dict[2] is inner_dict)  # prints True, they're the same dict
```

Here's a fixed version of the `outer_dict` definition that doesn't have that issue:

```
outer_dict = {1: inner_dict.copy(), 2: inner_dict.copy()}
```

In this version, `outer_dict[1]` and `outer_dict[2]` do not refer to the same inner dictionary any more, so you can edit their values independently of one another.

I suppose you could get away with not copying exactly one place you reference `inner_dict`, but it's probably not worth it, since you could easily make a mistake when editing the code later and get back to the original problem.

Comment: It seems `x is y is z` is equivalent to `x is y and y is z` as usual.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yep. I wrote it out, them doubted myself and had to test it to be sure, but `is` works just like other operators with respect to chaining.

Comment: @Blckknght: to be sure, I've compared `dis.dis('x <= y < z')` (that is known to work) with `dis.dis('x is y is z')`